# Android 13 how to handle don't allow notifications? How to explain reasons to allow?

Tags: kotlin, push-notification, onesignal, runtime-permissions, android-13

I want to explain users requirement of allowing permissions i.e., **opt in**

Starting from android 13 users are asked to opt-in for notifications.How can we handle this scenario.

Currently i want explain users importance of allowing notifications but what is the best way to show this message as the permission dialog is loading on app start immediately.

Answer (score 3):

Google recommends such a [user-driven workflow](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notification-permission#wait-to-show-prompt) for requesting notification permission for example:
[image]

First, you need to show your custom screen where you explain why the user needs the notifications. If he agreed to be notified then you can ask to grant the permission to show the native permission dialog.
Also, the custom screen is necessary only if `shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale()` returns `true` because if it's `false` then it means the user has already blocked it and can allow it again from system settings only.

Comment: Thank you, I was looking for shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale()